# Maya alembic exporting

Tags: export, maya

I am trying to export this geometry of mine as alembic.
While there does not seems to be any problems/errors encountered during the process, I noticed that one of the attribute that I have unchecked was checked upon importing the alembic.

The said attribute is 'Smooth UVs' which can be found under the shapeNode, Smooth Mesh - Extra Controls.

Was wondering if anyone could shed me some light as to this Extra Controls section, are they 'read' during the alembic export? Also whether if I can force the said attribute to be unchecked...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to it. Apparently, under the Export Options box, there is this Attributes Field.

Upon adding in an attribute as `smoothUVs` does the trick. And after importing this newly exported alembic, the attribute - smoothUVs is unchecked as how I want it to be